# Quickest way, from UV mapped shape to painting on the shape

Tags: texture-painting

Adding texture from an image file is easy. But I have to paint over it?

What is the quickest way to go from a shape with a UV map and use the texture paint tool?

Forgetting how to add a texture I fiddled around, now I'm painting a texture over gray? 
How did I do that?

[image]

Comment: You must have activated the texture paint mode after you uv unwrap your model. Picked a brush and started to paint over the model on the 3d viewport.